# Django Return Info Message If Database Unavailable

Tags: django

I have Django set up split database mode, with `default` being the write-primary, and `replica1` being a read-only replica.

I have routers enabled in Django settings so that writes go to the default db and `db_for_read` returns the `replica1` database.

However, when the read replica is down, the server still runs.  But requests spin forever and eventually timeout.

Is there a way to detect when the database is down, and if so, return an informational response instead of just spinning forever.  Maybe a middleware to check the connection or something in the view itself?

We don't want to allow read fallback on the primary database.